# For which $\kappa$ can we have if $\#\alpha=\#\beta=\kappa$, then the following also have cardinality $\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Suppose $\alpha,\beta$ are ordinals with cardinality $\kappa$. It can be proved by induction that if $\kappa=\aleph_0$, then $\alpha+\beta,\alpha\cdot\beta,\alpha^\beta$ also have cardinality $\kappa$.

But may I please ask：in general, for which $\kappa$ can we have $\#\alpha=\#\beta=\kappa$ implies the following:

(1)$\alpha+\beta$

(2)$\alpha\cdot\beta$

(3)$\alpha^\beta$

Has cardinality $\kappa$?

So far, I think that for any finite $\kappa\ne 0$, we cannot have (1)(2)(3) has the same cardinality $\kappa$. And for $\kappa=0$, the cardinality of (1)(2)(3) are all zero. And I think for any infinite $\kappa$, (1)(2)(3) has cardinality $\kappa$. Is that correct? Or if something is wrong, could someone give a correct argument with proof please? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: So is that the fact that:
When $\kappa=0$, the cardinality of (1)(2) are zero and thus has cardinality $\kappa$, (3) has cardinality $1$, so its cardinality is not $\kappa$.

When $\kappa\ne 0$, $\kappa$ is finite, the cardinality of (1)(2)(3) can never be $\kappa$.

When $\kappa$ is infinite, (1)(2)(3) has cardinality $\kappa$.

Could someone please confirm if these are fine now? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're right, except for $\kappa=0,$ because $0^0=1.$

Comment: @bof I think it is the correct way to compute the cardinality of ordinal number. But if possible, could you please show me explicitly that how can I see the fact that $\emptyset^\emptyset$ has cardinality $1$? It seems to me that it is so counterintuitive.

Comment: @PropositionX There is exactly one map from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$ - namely, the empty map $\emptyset$!

Comment: @BenWest Does the axiom of choice matter if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals?

Comment: If $\kappa = 1$, (2) and (3) have size $\kappa$, since $1\times 1 = 1$ and $1^1 = 1$.

Comment: @bof I didn't read closely enough, I assumed they were cardinals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\kappa$ is infinite, then it is true that $\alpha+\beta$, $\alpha\cdot\beta$, and $\alpha^\beta$ all have cardinality $\kappa$.  How you prove this depends on what definitions of ordinal arithmetic you have.  It is simplest to prove if you have explicit definitions of what the order types are: $\alpha+\beta$ is the disjoint union of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ordered such that $\beta$ comes after $\alpha$, $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is the Cartesian product $\beta\times\alpha$ with the lexicographic order, and $\alpha^\beta$ is the set of finite support functions $\beta\to\alpha$ with the lexicographic order with respect to the reverse order on $\beta$.  With these definitions, it is clear that $$|\alpha+\beta|=\kappa+\kappa=\kappa$$ and
$$|\alpha\cdot\beta|=\kappa\cdot\kappa=\kappa$$ (where the operations on the right are cardinal arithmetic).  For the exponential, note that there are only $\kappa$ many finite subsets of $\beta$ and only $\kappa$ functions from any finite set to $\alpha$, so $$|\alpha^\beta|\leq\kappa\cdot\kappa=\kappa.$$ On the other hand, clearly $|\alpha^\beta|\geq\kappa$, so $|\alpha^\beta|=\kappa$.

The finite case is easier, since then the ordinal arithmetic operations just coincide with the usual natural number operations and ordinals and cardinals are the same.  So if $\kappa>0$, $\alpha+\beta=\kappa+\kappa>\kappa$.  If $\kappa>1$, $\alpha\cdot\beta=\kappa\cdot\kappa>\kappa$ and $\kappa^\kappa>\kappa$.  On the other hand, for $\kappa=1$, we have $1\cdot 1=1$ and $1^1=1$.    And for $\kappa=0$, we have $0+0=0$ and $0\cdot 0=0$ (but $0^0=1$).  So there are no finite $\kappa$ such that all three of your conditions hold, although two of them hold for $\kappa=0$ and $\kappa=1$.